# XF.DLL/XFNet.DLL Documentation

Tags: .net, sockets, dll

I recently inherited a project that a previous contractor had put together for my company. The short version is that it is a collection of services, one runs on a client machine and connects to a server service. The person who wrote it used a third party DLL called XFNet.DLL. After googling around for a few hours I found that the DLL was publish by Kodart Technologies(I think). I'm unable to find any other useful documentation on the DLL(ie. Error codes, function signatures).

Does anyone have a reliable link to any form of documentation on this dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ILSpy if you don't find the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately ILSpy requires .Net 4.0 and this particular project is still in 3.5. But I did try to use .Net Reflector on the dll but it said it wasn't a .net dll and couldn't be decompiled.

Comment: The issue turned out to be that i needed to use reflector on the xfnet.dll instead of the xf.dll file. for whatever reason xf.dll couldn't be decompiled by reflector.